# Essential Reading for New GM/DM

Tags: gm-techniques, new-gm

I'm preparing to take the plunge into GM'ing. What would you be consider essential reading for a new gm? Books, websites, etc.?

I really want to focus in on being a good story teller.

Comment: Which game are you planning to run?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, but I'm in the car.

Comment: @mxyzplk [This one](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1113/4398) was closed as too opinion-based; [this one](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/791/4398) as too broad; [this one](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/15580/4398) is about combat tactics; and [this one](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/22625/4398) might be a dupe but I'm not sure.

Comment: I believe this is a poor fit for RPG.SE. The trouble is that there *is* no such thing as "essential" reading for a new GM, but everyone has an opinion on what's good to read. (And purely opinion-based stuff is off-topic for [important reasons](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3398/whats-so-problematic-about-a-recommendation-question-having-potentially-hundred).)

Comment: @Strategon, welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [about] and the [help]; they're a useful introduction to the site. As you can see, we've struggled with this kind of question before. Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, rather than a forum, and super-broad opinion-based questions like this don't really fit that format. However, if you can edit in more information about your particular situation and the things you're concerned about, it could turn into an awesome question with answers that will be actually useful. Until then, it'll probably be put on hold to avoid gathering non-useful answers.